# Bring a view on absolute position to front in react native

Tags: react-native, z-index, react-native-stylesheet

This is happening on with Android and on iOS it's working fine. I have a component that has a badge which I also custom-made.

```
function HomeMenuCell({ title, imagePath, pressEvent, showBadge, badgeText }) {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container} onPress={pressEvent}>
            <View style={styles.imageView}>
                <Image source={imagePath} />
            </View>
            <Text style={styles.titleText}>{title}</Text>
            {showBadge && <View style={styles.badgeView}>
                <Text style={styles.badgeText}>{badgeText}</Text>
            </View>}
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
```

I have a `TouchableOpacity` component and in this container, I'm doing everything. The `badgeView` is also positioned based on the `container`

```
    container: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginBottom: 10,
        marginTop: 10,
        marginRight: 10,
        marginLeft: 20
    },
    badgeView: {
        position: 'absolute',
        backgroundColor: 'pink',
        borderRadius: 8,
        padding: 3,
        // zInndex: 999, //This doesn't work
        right: 0,
        top: 0
    },
```

But it is hidden behind the `imageView`

```
    imageView: {
        width: 50, height: 50,
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
        shadowColor: 'black',
        shadowOpacity: 0.2,
        elevation: 3,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderRadius: 8,
    },
```

I even tried putting those lines of code before. I think it's because the props are not loaded and the view gets rendered. So, any ideas?

Created this quick Snack (Only see in Android): https://snack.expo.io/@chtalha/badge-on-view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   badgeView: {
    position: 'absolute',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    borderRadius: 8,
    padding: 3,
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 3.84,
    elevation: 5,
    right: -15,
    top: -5
},
```

Use this style in your badgeView hope this will work for you :)
This this happen because you already use elevation in image so if you wanna display your other view on top of it then you must set higher elevation compare to image view